# Specifying the number of points sampled by NDSolve, and the meaning of "steps"

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

I am working with lists generated from interpolating functions given by `NDSolve`.

Manipulating the lists, I encountered a problem - the lists, of course, need to be of equal length, but `NDSolve` gives interpolating functions with some number of points I can not find a way to specify.

I tried to combine `MaxSteps` and `MaxStepSize` to force it to take the exact number of steps I want, but apparently, the number of steps **isn't** the length of the corresponding list. The length is always larger. How come? What do "steps" mean, if not the points sampled in the range given to `NDSolve`?

Is there a way to specify the number of points in the interpolating function, that is, the length of the corresponding list?

Comment: Not too easy to answer your question without an example that can be evaluated.

Comment: You can use the ["FixedStep" method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveFixedStep.html) and give up the adaptive step-size control that keeps the error within certain goals.

Comment: Depending on what the goal is, a list of any length can be obtained from an interpolating function by using, for instance, `Table`.